# How to include a file in my .zshrc?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, zshrc

I normally use Github for my dotfiles. For a gem I am working on, I need to add some private keys to my `.zshrc`.

Is there a way for me to include another file in my `.zshrc`, where I can store my environment variables in that included file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, by using the `source` command:

```
# environment variables
source ~/.zsh_env_vars
```

Comment: Note for newbies like myself: Syntax for ENVs in shell is different from using ENVs in Ruby or Rails projects: `export MY_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your .zshrc or .zshenv file to iterate through a directory. That makes it possible to seperate your variables. Maybe you want to have a specific file for $PATH and one for your ruby variables, ...

`for file in ~/.zsh_variables/*; do if [ -f "$file" ]; then source "$file" fi done`